# AutoHotkey: Test for key sequence?

Tags: sequence, autohotkey

What I mean is that if I press the A key, it then tests for the B key on the second key press, then if it is, it tests for the C key. If any are not the key it's waiting for, it goes back to the A key.

Comment: use [input](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm)

Comment: Sounds like a Password or PASSWORD or password..

Comment: also sounds like a [hotstring](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotstrings.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by Assigning Key A as a [Hotkey](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm) and then having a [Input](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/Input.htm) command evaluate the next key press. Evaulate the key pressed using [If](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/IfExpression.htm) command, If true, then have another Input command evaluate the next key press etc etc ...

There appears to be Example code of this method on the Input page in the Docs.

```
; This is a working hotkey example.  Since the hotkey has the tilde (~)
; prefix, its own keystroke will pass through to the active window.
; Thus, if you type [btw (or one of the other match
; phrases) in any editor, the script will automatically perform an
; action of your choice (such as replacing the typed text):

~[::
Input, UserInput, V T5 L4 C, {enter}.{esc}{tab}, btw,otoh,fl,ahk,ca
if (ErrorLevel = "Max")
{
    MsgBox, You entered "%UserInput%", which is the maximum length of text.
    return
}
if (ErrorLevel = "Timeout")
{
    MsgBox, You entered "%UserInput%" at which time the input timed out.
    return
}
if (ErrorLevel = "NewInput")
    return
If InStr(ErrorLevel, "EndKey:")
{
    MsgBox, You entered "%UserInput%" and terminated the input with %ErrorLevel%.
    return
}
; Otherwise, a match was found.
if (UserInput = "btw")
    Send, {backspace 4}by the way
else if (UserInput = "otoh")
    Send, {backspace 5}on the other hand
else if (UserInput = "fl")
    Send, {backspace 3}Florida
else if (UserInput = "ca")
    Send, {backspace 3}California
else if (UserInput = "ahk")
    Run, http://ahkscript.org
return
```

To modify the Input to only accept 1 key stroke you simple change the Option on the Input command from L4 to L1 and put whatever key you want as in Quotes as a match list, for example.

Example Not Tested but should be close to what you want:

```
~A::
Input, UserInput, V T5 L1, , "B"

If (UserInput = "B")
     Input, UserInput, V T5 L1, , "C"
         If (UserInput = "C")
            .... Some more code here...
```